# ServiceNotCreatedException in Zend Framework 2 while attempting multiple navigations

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I am attempting to create multiple navigation menus to use in my application based on a specific user role. The majority of the code is similar to zfc-admin. When I use zfc-admin in my application I am able to bring up an admin menu, however I will have about four roles, and decided to put this in my Application module.

`module.config.php`

```
'navigation' => array(
    'admin' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Admin Home',
            'route' => 'adminhome',
        ),
    ),
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
        ),
    ),
),
```

`AdminNavigationFactory.php`

```
namespace Application\Navigation\Service;
use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class AdminNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getName()
    {
        return 'admin';
    }
}
```

`Module.php`

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'admin_navigation' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\AdminNavigationFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

`layout.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('admin_navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

I get the error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException' with message 'While attempting to create adminnavigation(alias: admin_navigation) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 987
```

If I change the layout.phtml to use the default menu everything works as expected.

```
<?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu(); ?>
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem now, did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get it working. I ended up using a view helper that returned the correct menu based on the user's role.

Comment: I got it to work. The problem for me was that I was putting AdminNavigationFactory.php in the directory /module/Admin/src/Navigation/Service/ and the correct directory to put it is /module/Admin/src/Admin/Navigation/Service/. I hope you can get it working too.

Answer (score 0):

first I got exactly the same issue. After moving the factory configuration from the getServiceConfig() method in the module class to the module.config.php it worked.

So my admin navigation works now like the follows:

### module.config.php

(module/Admin/config/module.config.php)

```php
return array(
    // yada yada yada...
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
            'adminnav' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\AdminNavigationFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'navigation'      => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Filme',
                'route' => 'movies',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Admin',
                'route' => 'admin',
            ),
        ),
        'adminnav' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Film hinzufügen',
                'route' => 'add-movie',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Buch hinzufügen',
                'route' => 'add-book',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

### AdminNavigationFactory

(module/Application/src/Application/Navigation/Service/AdminNavigationFactory.php)

```php
namespace Application\Navigation\Service;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class AdminNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    protected function getName()
    {
        return 'adminnav';
    }
}
```

Maybe you want to check out the code in context of the entire application, so here are the links to the my github:

1. [AdminNavigationFactory](https://github.com/Foomy/pollux/blob/master/module/Application/src/Application/Navigation/Service/AdminNavigationFactory.php)
2. [module.config.php](https://github.com/Foomy/pollux/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php)

Regards,
Sascha