# have more than 1 navigation in zend 2.3

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I searched to find out how can I use 2 navigations in ZF 2.3 and I find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972316/how-to-set-up-2-navigations-in-zf2)

I used the given answer, but I am getting this error message:

```
ServiceNotCreatedException in Zend Framework 2 while attempting multiple navigations
```

I searched for this  and find  this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003514/servicenotcreatedexception-in-zend-framework-2-while-attempting-multiple-navigat)

And at least I can't have 2 navigator what should I do? I searched in ZF2.3 documention on zend website but it has only an example of default navigator.

Answer (score 1):

finally i find out this problem solved in ZF 2.4  so i upgraded my zend version and my problem was solved.

ZF 2.4 have example for having more than 1 navigator.